# Ternary operator is always false

Tags: c, ternary-operator

I am working on a project within C code and trying to use a ternary if statement but its always returning false and I don't understand why.

The ternary if statement is:

```
(reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] == '\0') ? reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] : "HELLO"
```

What I am trying to do is if `reportParameterArray[P_TARGET]` doesn't equal to \0 then it should output the actual value otherwise it prints hello. But at the moment it always prints `HELLO`.

When I debug I can see that the value is \0 so it should print "HELLO" but when there is an actual value it still prints HELLO and not the actual value of reportParameterArray[P_TARGET].

reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] is of type char**

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: have you tried to check for `(reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] == NULL)`?

Comment: `reportParameterArray[P_TARGET]` seems to be a `char` while  `"HELLO"` is a string. If you mean a null pointer, use NULL instead of `'\0'`.

Comment: reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] is of type ``char**``. I've tried using NULL instead of \0 but get the same result

Comment: It is working fine, Check pointer assignment -> `char **reportParameterArray = ?` <- Is correct or not

Comment: with (reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] == '\0') you are comparing a char pointer to a char.

Comment: @peko yea you were right I should have been referencing it as ``*reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] == '\0'`` Now its working as expected. Would you like to put this as an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for

```
(reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] == NULL)
```

because with

```
(reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] == '\0')
```

you are comparing a char pointer to a char.

```
(*reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] == '\0')
```

is actually OK - '\0' is an integer value of zero, and in this context is evaluated as a null pointer constant, but if you mean NULL, just say NULL

Comment: Shouldn't the null char literal get extended?

Comment: '\0' is just an integer value of zero, NULL is ((void*)0). the have the same value, but a different type

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operation takes the form

```
condition ? when true : when false;
```

e.g

```
(var == 2) ? "Var equals 2!" : "Var doesn't equal 2!";
```

Hence you have your condition backwards.

Comment: I've tried both ways, and changed what I have to be  != instead and this time it always prints what is in the array never. I.e. if the value in the array is empty it outputs a blank string instead of HELLO

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers said, your conditional is backwards. But you're also comparing a `char*` to a `char`. You want to check the first character in the string, like so:

```
(reportParameterArray[P_TARGET][0] != '\0') ? reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] : "HELLO"
```

This is of course assuming you want to check for an empty string, and not a string that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary operator expression is backwards. You mean:

```
(reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] != '\0') ? reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] : "HELLO"
```

Or alternately:

```
(reportParameterArray[P_TARGET] == '\0') ? "HELLO" : reportParameterArray[P_TARGET]
```

Comment: I've tried both ways, I've changed it to ``!=`` again and this time it always prints what is in the array never ``HELLO``